# JAX pmap is slower than jit(vmap), how to speedup?

Tags: python, jit, jax, pmap

I have two fairly complex and independent computations that I want to run on two GPUs with `pmap`.
Surprisingly the `pmap`-ed version is much slower.
I know that doubling the performance is almost impossible but I expected a better performance.

Below is the complete example that mimics my workload (it requires `haiku` and `chex`).
The model is different but the logic is more or less the same.
Any suggestions on what I can do to speed up the whole computation?

```py
import contextlib
import time
from typing import NamedTuple

import chex
import haiku as hk
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
import numpy as np
from absl import app, logging

@contextlib.contextmanager
def timer(name: str):
    begin = time.time_ns()
    try:
        yield begin
    finally:
        logging.info(f'Timer {name}[ms] {(time.time_ns() - begin) / int(1e6)}')


class Input(NamedTuple):
    x: chex.Array
    a: chex.Array
    b: chex.Array


@hk.without_apply_rng
@hk.transform
def net(x: Input) -> chex.Array:
    return hk.nets.MLP([128, 128,128, 1])((x.x - x.a) * x.b)


apply_for_many = jax.vmap(net.apply, in_axes=(None, Input(None, 0, 0)))


def main(_):
    rng = jax.random.PRNGKey(42)

    x = np.random.normal(size=(16, 8))
    a = np.random.normal(size=(64))
    b = np.random.normal(size=(64))

    params = net.init(rng, Input(x, a[0], b[0]))

    lr = jnp.logspace(-5, -2, jax.device_count())

    def cost(x: chex.Array, a: chex.Array, b: chex.Array, params: hk.Params) -> chex.Array:
        yhat = apply_for_many(params, Input(x, a, b))
        return jnp.mean(yhat)

    def update(params: hk.Params, x: Input, lr: chex.Array) -> chex.Array:
        df = jax.grad(cost)(*x, params)
        proposal = x.x - lr * df
        proposal = jnp.where(proposal < 0., 0., proposal)
        value = cost(proposal, a, b, params)
        return value, proposal

    jv_update = jax.jit(jax.vmap(update, in_axes=(None, None, 0)))
    p_update = jax.pmap(update, in_axes=(None, None, 0))

    @jax.jit
    def select(values: chex.Array, proposals: chex.Array) -> chex.Array:
        min_idx = jnp.argmin(values)
        return proposals[min_idx, ...]

    # jit
    v, p = jv_update(params, Input(x, a, b), lr)
    v, p = p_update(params, Input(x, a, b), lr)
    new_x = select(v, p).block_until_ready()

    with timer('pmap()'):
        v, p = p_update(params, Input(x + 0.1, a, b), lr)
        new_x = select(v, p).block_until_ready()

    with timer('jit(vmap())'):
        v, p = jv_update(params, Input(x + 0.1, a, b), lr)
        new_x = select(v, p).block_until_ready()


    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(main)
```

And example results fro a node with 2 V100 GPUs:

```
I1209 20:33:09.194915 47073222112192 pmap_vmap_benchmark.py:18] Timer pmap()[ms] 2.554325
I1209 20:33:09.195681 47073222112192 pmap_vmap_benchmark.py:18] Timer jit(vmap())[ms] 0.430292
```

Comment: Since your input is not a sharded array, I suspect the issue is that the pmap version is including device transfer costs, while the vmap is not. You might try calling `device_put_sharded` outside the benchmark to isolate this.

Comment: @jakevdp You are right sharding helped but also I needed to increase the number of layers for pamp to win. Having said that the overall gain is still ~20%. It looks like `pmap` is helpful for really large computations.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. GPUs are specifically designed for on-chip parallel computation. If you're doing a small computation that already fits on a single GPU, you won't gain anything by sharding it to multiple GPUs, and associated data transfer overhead may even make the end-to-end runtime slower.